# What's the difference between "no" and "not"?

Tags: grammar

> Helen is not beautiful, and her sister is not, either.
>   =Helen is _____ beautiful than her sister.
>   (A) no more
>   (B) not more

The answer is (A). 
Why can't choose "not more"?

Answer (score 1):

We are told that Helen is not beautiful and her sister is not beautiful.

A is correct because "Person 1 is **no more** [something] **than** person 2" means "Person 1 is not [something] and neither is Person 2".

B is incorrect because "not more than" means "less than or equal to". "Helen is not more beautiful than her sister" means that Helen's sister may be beautiful, and Helen may be too, but not more so.

> no more ... than
>
> used to emphasize that someone or something does not have a particular
>   quality or would not do something
>
> He’s no more fit to be a priest than I am!

[No more... than](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/no-more-than)